# Rendering problem

Tags: davinci-resolve

I have a very big problem with rendering my video in Davinci Resolve 17.
Every time i render a video it doesn't start at the beginning and it's rendering 1 clip only.
I am trying to finish a 3 minute video, but when IO render, I only get 20 seconds video.

Same thing to copy/paste adjustment clips:
Whenever I paste the adjustment/text I had copied, then it'll paste only at 1 spot, and that spot is also where the render starts, and that clip is the only clip that's getting rendered.
I hope someone can help me to finish my project.

Answer (score 1):

On the Deliver page there is an option to process Single Clip or Individual Clips.  Choose Single clip. It is in the left-side menu close to the area where you choose the path and output options.

[image: Render Settings]

Also, make sure you don't have any in-out areas selected on your timeline page or it will just render that out. Alt+X will clear all in-out points.

Comment: @Kerby you should accept (and up-vote) the answer if it helped.